# How to load package module without importing functions in Julia

Tags: julia

I can do that with relative paths `include("./lib/finance.jl")` and use as `Finance.some_finance_fn()`.

But how to do the same with packages? `include("statistics.jl")` is not working. And if I include it as `using Statistics` all the functions will be exported in the current scope. I would like to avoid that and call it like `Statistics.mean` not `mean`.

P.S.

Because sometimes it conflicts with local variable names and I can't name variable `mean` because it conflicts wiht `mean` functions exported from `Statistics` module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`import`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#import) keyword (see [Modules](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/index.html#Summary-of-module-usage-1) documentation):

```
julia> import Statistics

julia> mean
ERROR: UndefVarError: mean not defined

julia> Statistics.mean
mean (generic function with 5 methods)
```

For comparison, with the [`using`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#using) keyword all exported identifiers are brought into the current scope:

```
julia> using Statistics

julia> mean
mean (generic function with 5 methods)

julia> Statistics.mean
mean (generic function with 5 methods)
```